# How to remove all secondary groups from a user

Tags: linux

I need to remove all groups from user.

```
id test12
uid=4050(test12) gid=100(users) groups=100(users),50000(test1)
```

how can I remove all secondary groups (users, test1)

There is a way to remove them in once ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `usermod` from `shadow-utils-2 4.6-14`. It also works in the version on Debian 11 and the latest Arch.

```
usermod -G test12 test12
```

Output of `id -nG test12`

```
test12
```

Comment: I need to remove them in a script, there is something like

usermod -G * test12

Comment: You should detail your question a little bit. Which users should be affected? Where should the script be runnable? ...

Comment: thanks that did answer my question, the fact doing usermod without -a flag. It did remove other groups

Answer (score 1):

> How can I remove all secondary groups (`users`, `test1`)?

By providing an empty string as the option-argument for `usermod -G` and not using `-a`:

```
usermod -G '' test12
```

Note `users` in your example is *not* a supplementary group; it's the primary group. To remove `test12` from `users` you need to set another group as the primary group (`usermod -g …`). This has nothing to do with supplementary groups.